# UV/Image Editor, pink circle cursor

Tags: uv-image-editor

sorry for asking this because I suppose it's a very obvious question but here it goes: I don't know which key I've pressed but when I enter in UV/Imager Editor mode the pointer looks like some kind of pink circle and I'm not able to work as usually. Can someone tell me how can I back to the normal UV/Image Edit mode?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Probably UV sculpt mode. It appears using the 'Q' key. Use 'Q' again to exit this mode (keeping mouse cursor inside the UV/image editor).

Comment: That's it @lemon, many thanks, I have the basics in Blender but never messed with this 'UV sculp mode' u_u" Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have hit the **Q** key. I think its someing like "sculpting for UV editing" 
With your mouse hovering over the UV/image editor window tapping the Q key again will toggle it back to the regular selection mode.

Comment: Fixed it for me - cheers.